# CSS :after input placeholder not working in mozilla

Tags: css, placeholder

I want to put a small icon in my text input placeholder **right where my placeholder text ends**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search  ">
```

With CSS I want to add a magnifier icon. This works perfectly in Chrome, but I want to make it work for Firefox as well.

For Chrome I used `::-webkit-input-placeholder:after{content:url('magnifier.jpg');}`
And with Firefox I've tried

```
input:-moz-placeholder:after{content:url('magnifier.jpg');}
```

and

```
input:-moz-placeholder::after{content:url('magnifier.jpg');}
```

but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24076889/607874 might be useful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.......................

Input elements are replaced elements.

`Pseudo-elements`, such as `:after`  or `:before` will not work on

```
 <button>, <textarea>, <input>,  <select>, <img>, <object>
```

**[these](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)** elements.

***[More info](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)***

Comment: The `:after` and `:before` may or may not work on e.g. `input` elements. This depends on the browser, and it is a gray area in the CSS 2.1 spec (and not clarified in CSS3 Selectors spec).

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to add the image as content. Use

```
input:-moz-placeholder { background: url('magnifier.jpg') right center no-repeat }
```

and tweak the background properties to taste.

Comment: I asked this because I also want to add a red asterix * right where my placeholder text ends, which again, is not working in mozilla

Comment: @Vodaldrien: Does that have anything to do with the question you actually asked?