# 2 colors in one placeholder of input field

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need create input which has 2 colors in a placeholder.

and here is solution which works well in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/vmuJm/

## html

```
<input placeholder="Name" class="required" />
```

## css

```
.required::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
.required:-moz-placeholder:after {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
.required::-moz-placeholder:after {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
.required:-ms-input-placeholder:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
```

But my current FF 29.0.1 doesn't show content from :after, so this solution doesn't work. Is there any other way to get 2 colors in one placeholder with css and html?

## Chrome:

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-NN7pPNg49D8/U5DUKMAIJhI/AAAAAAAAzAg/LqltLDSNgD4/s0/2014-06-05_22-33-08.png]

## FF:

[image]

Comment: @Eugene Did you tested my solution? Some problem found?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a cross-browser solution that does not use Javascript:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K7ffK/2/)

Inline elements such `input` do not support `:before` and `:after`. To make things even harder the placeholder selector and their pseudo-classes are not fully supported by all browsers, as you found out.

So, the workaround is to add a `label` placed relatively on top of the input box with a `for` attribute pointing to the input text box. This way, when user clicks the label (fake placeholder) the focus goes into the input box underneath.

Replace your `class="required"` by the attribute `required="required"`. This gives you an opportunity to use the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) and [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) selectors, and also lets the browser display a validation error, when the form is submitted with empty required fields.

```css
input {
  width: 160px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: auto;
}

input[required]+label {
  color: #999;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: .8em;
  position: relative;
  left: -166px;
  /* the negative of the input width */
}

input[required]+label:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}


/* show the placeholder when input has no content (no content = invalid) */

input[required]:invalid+label {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* hide the placeholder when input has some text typed in */

input[required]:valid+label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Since the email is not required, leave the native placeholder there, and just to this hack for the name.

I also changed your email from `type="text"` to `type="email"` for better user experience on mobile devices.

Comment: what a bloody great use of required!!

Comment: What if we need it for more than one field  http://jsfiddle.net/w7mc380g/  works(hides lable) only for first input box. Any way to get this code working for multiple fields?

Comment: Figured out . Here is working fiddle for multiple fields http://jsfiddle.net/0j9f7pL1/

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Jose's solution, without using "required" attribute, the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K7ffK/76/) also can do what you want.

Key point is css has `:not` selector, refer to [Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

Answer (score 0):

Same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834939/css-after-input-placeholder-not-working-in-mozilla)

Basically the answer is no. Depends on the browser.

`:before` and `:after` can not be used on some elements such as `<input>`. It Depends on the browser though, as it seems like chrome can do it.

Maybe it can be solved using JavaScript? I don't know