# Input placeholder with different color asterisk?

Tags: css, forms, placeholder

I'm looking to have a placeholder text like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name: *" />
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to get the * to be a different color. There are many solutions on here that don't work in modern browsers anymore.

Comment: The image that you put in doesn't open.

Comment: I think that this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069830/2-colors-in-one-placeholder-of-input-field

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy placeholder with input value and on focus/blur just hide/show respectively the placeholder.