# How to achieve custom placholder with effect only on required fields in Angular

Tags: css, angular

Could you tell me how i can create input with placeholder like below?
[image]

My current input field looks similar but it has simple placeholder without styled astrix.

```
  <input
    class="form-control"
    [formControl]="ngControl.control"
    placeholder="Email"
    />
```

I have prepared condition which checks if current field is required

```
ngControl.control.getError('required')
```

So i've tried something like this

```
  <div class='input-container border'>
        <input
        class="form-control"
        [formControl]="ngControl.control"
        placeholder="Email"
        />
        <div *ngIf="ngControl.control.getError('required')" class="required-field">Email <span>*</span></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069830/2-colors-in-one-placeholder-of-input-field) can help you for placeholder with two color, and you can bind your control to input requierd attribute.

like this:

```
<input [required]="ngControl.control.getError('required')"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `required` attribute inside in the input field.