# Why I don't have a red star after placeholder in browser Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to put a red star after placeholder. Both Chrome and Safari are OK, but doesn't work at Firefox.
What I did is

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {  content: "*";
    color: red; }
input::-moz-placeholder:after {  content: "*";
    color: red; }
input:-ms-input-placeholder:after {  content: "*";
    color: red; }
```

in CSS and

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" >
</div>
```

in HTML.
Why there is nothing after `Email` in FIrefox.

Comment: What is in your link is:

::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}

Not:

input::-webkit-input-placeholder:after

I am not familiar with the "::" syntax in css, but if you just follow the example it'll probably work.

Comment: @sscotti, they are same

Comment: Now I found that chrome and safari are fine. Just chrome has problem.

Comment: Not sure that you got your answer re mozilla.  If not this might help:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069830/2-colors-in-one-placeholder-of-input-field), from another stack overflow post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ::after pseudo only works with -input-placeholder (or -placeholder) in Chrome. Notice in this fiddle,

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

work in Firefox and IE, respectively, but not

```
input::-moz-placeholder:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrb38504/)

Comment: yeah that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle example that you gave has:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
}
```

You have input before the :: ?

Comment: Now I found that chrome and safari are fine. Just chrome has problem.

Comment: Might look at this.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834939/css-after-input-placeholder-not-working-in-mozilla), there must be a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure that feature is universally supported (i.e. mozilla).  Not sure that you can specify 2 pseudo elements in one declaration.  2 pseudo classes it seems yet, 2 pseudo elements maybe not.  Have to research that a bit.

Comment: Also maybe read this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

Comment: This might work for you from stack overflow, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069830/2-colors-in-one-placeholder-of-input-field), see below also.