# Input with multiple colors with Vanilla-JS or Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

What's the best way to have an input with two colors? I need to attach (in Angular I will use a pipe for that) a not-yet-typed part/placeholder of an id and it should have a lighter color than the typed input. E.g. `123456XXX` after the user has typed 123456, and the `XXX` is a grey instead of black color?

If it was a span, I could put a `<grey>` around the suffix, with a grey style assigned to it, but an  cannot contain other html-tags

It needs to run in IE11! If you know an addon that does that, feel free to post it as a comment, I can look up the solution myself.

Comment: Did u try a div tag (instead of input)? with the content editable set to true? I hope then u can use html tags and classes for styling.

Comment: I am afraid this is what I will have to do, although a classic input would be better for various reasons (native handling on all browsers etc). in Angular you can access and set the input content with `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, but I see no way of applying a style to the content

Comment: Ok I just saw this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834939/css-after-input-placeholder-not-working-in-mozilla looks like I'm out of luck on this one ^^

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <span>
    Part 1
  </span>
  <span style="color: red">
     Part 2
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish there was a way using native `<input>`. I guess no?